# How to load all tables from access database into a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I'm new to programming and have been looking for quite a while on the internet on how to resolve my issue but sadly with no success. Can some of you please help me out?

So I have an access database with different tables and I want all tables to appear in a combobox for example: tblFood, tblCars, tblAnimals...

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\School\Stage\Program testen\Program\bin\Debug\InventoryDB.accdb");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = con;
    string query = "Select * from ALL THE TABELS IN ACCESS";
    command.CommandText = query;

    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        comboBoxTabel.Items.Add(reader["ADD THE TABLES TO COMBOBOX"].ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the [OleDbConnection.GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135982(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
using(OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection("......"))
{
    cnn.Open();
    DataTable dt = cnn.GetSchema("TABLES");
    foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine(r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
}
```

Keep in mind that this returns a lot of noise. I mean that you will find in the DataTable returned by GetSchema also system objects and views. You could filter them out using the TABLE_TYPE column which describe the object type.
For example, you could get only the user tables using a syntax like this

```
DataTable dt = cnn.GetSchema("TABLES")
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(x => 
                   x.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE")
                  .CopyToDataTable();
```

Another method to filter the output is using the [overload of GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135983(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an array of string called [Schema Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey ty for answering! Sry to say I'm only programming for around 2months now. I'm not entirely sure how to edit your answer into my code so that it shows up in the combobox :/ could you please do this for me cause when i try to do it myself i seem to mess up

Comment: ty! but now i get other stuff with the tables https://gyazo.com/4de915170fed4dd4fc2b43b016247c36 would i be possible just to show this?https://gyazo.com/ffeed846f61c723c7a90d5cbb7940ad4

Comment: Did you see the last edit I have made to the answer? The part with _a lot of noise_?

Comment: Apologies somehow I missed it. It seems to have helped quite a bunch only there remains 1 more thing that doesn't have to be there https://gyazo.com/2d8c17286b8718fae984bcfea39c45b5 BTW ty for helping me out so much

Comment: http://www.accessjunkie.com/Pages/faq2010_32.aspx This seems the by-product of some manual interaction with your database. Probably following the link you could simply remove that table or use a check on the table name to avoid adding it to the combobox

Comment: My apologies I understand :c I was just being to hasty with my questions, I guess when a problem with programming is solved a new one shows up :D ty for helping me out this much!